Slow boot times Ubuntu 24.04
New to Ubuntu 24.04 after having taken a break from Linux the past 15 years. System was snappy and quick to boot at first but has now slowed to over two minutes from grub to login screen. (Win10 will spin up very quickly, about 30s on this system) The only startup programs that I have currently are Nvidia settings and SSH key agent. Looking at systemd-analyze blame, it would appear that it's taking a -very- long time thinking about "dev-sda3.device" on boot and not an appreciable time thinking about anything else. (My root partition is sda3, an SSD)
See highlights from systemd-analyze blame output:
2min 9.422s dev-sda3.device
11.862s apt-daily.service
 6.651s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 5.650s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 2.600s logrotate.service
 2.413s NetworkManager.service
 2.138s gpu-manager.service
 1.380s systemd-journal-flush.service
 1.142s snapd.seeded.service
 1.041s snapd.service
 1.035s gnome-remote-desktop.service

Any clues or things to try? Thanks in advance.

30s to boot is yet very slow nowadays. Modern computers shall boot in a few seconds. What SSD do you have ? SATA or NVMe ? How old is it ?

Could be a failing hard drive.  Checking kernel logs might be interesting.

Feeling like an idiot - but posting this answer to potentially help others.
I had an old USB hard drive plugged in that I loaded a bunch of backed up things onto the computer after I set up Ubuntu. I tried rebooting after unplugging it - and that solved my problem. 15 second boot time after unplugging the old USB hard drive. Would be interesting to know why having an old hard drive plugged into USB would affect boot time, but I'll leave it unplugged unless I need something off of it.
